# Declaring and using a C function in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, c

This must be very simple, but I can't figure out how to do this: I have a C-function to monitor current memory usage:

```
natural_t report_memory(void) {
    struct task_basic_info info;
    mach_msg_type_number_t size = sizeof(info);
    kern_return_t kerr = task_info(mach_task_self(),
                               TASK_BASIC_INFO,
                               (task_info_t)&info,
                               &size);
    if( kerr == KERN_SUCCESS ) {
        return info.resident_size;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error with task_info(): %s", mach_error_string(kerr));
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to use it. How do I declare it in the .h?
I tried the (for me) obvious within the objective c methods:

```
natural_t report_memory(void);
```

Calling this somewhere in the code:

```
NSLog(@"Memory used: %u", rvC.report_memory());
```

The Compiler complains `error: called object  is not a function`. Thus, I assume, the declaration is somehow wrong. I tried several options, but the best I could get was a runtime error...
How to fix this?

Comment: Did you declare it as an instance method ?

Comment: And what is the type of `rvC`?

Comment: rvC is the RootViewController, where the code resides.

Comment: I probably would want to have an instance method? Or is it possible to use the code from a class method?

Comment: Since the function has no relation whatsoever to view controllers, I would keep it as a C function (declared in a separate header file, defined in a separate implementation file). You can use it from instance or class methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
rvC.report_memory()
```

should be replaced with

```
report_memory()
```

since it is a C function.

Comment: but I want to use it from different classes

Comment: @angrest C functions are independent of classes. Simply call `report_memory()` wherever you need it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use this function in other modules, you should also put in your header (.h) file this line

```
extern natural_t report_memory(void);
```